# How to convert a pandas series of objects into a dataframe where each item becomes a column and the values in the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am stuck at this:
I have a Series with the following structure
Name: sn
dtype: object

```
0 { key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3} 
1 { key1: value4, key2: value5, key3: value6} 
2 { key1: value7, key2: value8, key3: value9} 
3 { key1: value10, key2: value11, key3: value12}
```

I want to transform it into a DataFrame

```
   <key1>     <key2>    <key3>  # columns
0  <value1>   <value2>  <value3>
1  <value4>   <value5>  <value6>
2  <value7>   <value8>  <value9>
3  <value10>   <value11>  <value12>
```

I have tried using:

```
cols = ['key1','key2','key3']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=sn_sites['sn'], index=cols)
```

I was also able to iterate over the series and print item keys I need.

```
for index, value in sn.items():
  print (f{value['key1']}, {value['key3']) # works 
  df['column1'] = value['key1'] # doesn't work
```

But I still need a dataframe as output so I can progress on building my structure with columns from other dataframes and values like this inside series.
Is there an simple way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, this should work:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Series` contains a `dict` in each row. Pandas can construct a `DataFrame` from structured input data like your `Series` using [pd.DataFrame.from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html).

```py
import pandas as pd

raw = [
    {"key1": 1, "key2": 2, "key3": 3},
    {"key1": 4, "key2": 5, "key3": 6},
    {"key1": 7, "key2": 8, "key3": 9},
]

# Each element is a dict
d_series = pd.Series(raw)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(d_series)
```

You can also unpack the `Series` right into the `DataFrame` constructor.

```py
pd.DataFrame(*d_series)
```